# Difficulty Connecting to Wi-Fi Network After Ubuntu 20.04 Upgrade

Tags: 20.04

After upgrading my system to Ubuntu 20.04, I've been experiencing difficulties connecting to my home Wi-Fi network. Previously, I had no issues with connectivity on Ubuntu 18.04. However, since the upgrade, my system seems to have trouble identifying and connecting to the network.

I've double-checked the Wi-Fi password and tried restarting both my router and computer, but the problem persists. Other devices in my household can connect to the Wi-Fi without any issues, so I suspect it's a problem specific to my Ubuntu system.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to diagnose and resolve this Wi-Fi connectivity issue on Ubuntu 20.04? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Look in `journalctl -b -0 -r -u NetworkManager -u wpa_supplicant`

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu. For questions about wifi, it's usually advised to run the [wireless info script](https://askubuntu.com/a/425180), that is also referenced in the [various other answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/425205) to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos). Just edit your question and provide a pastebin link to the output.